Regex : How do I recognize multiple patterns in one expression to gather a string? (UIPATH)
PA Line Item02StatusAPPROVED
COS Code430Category of ServiceNurse
Units Allowed1Amount Allowed$0.00  

PA Line Item03StatusAPPROVED
COS Code770Category of ServiceNurse
Units Allowed1Amount Allowed$0.00  

For instance : If I want to grab between Item and Status, then between Code and Category, how would I go about it to return (02430,03770) ?
I've tried ((?<=Item).*(?=Status))((?<=Code).*(?=Category)) but I must need an AND symbol.

like so: Item(\d+)Status|Code(\d+)Category?

This gives me back ( Item02Status , Code430Category , Item03Status , Code770Category ), but I want ( 02430 , 03770 )

@AlyssaRichmond Try: (?<=Item).*(?=Status)|(?<=Code).*(?=Category)

To get ( 02430 , 03770 ) from that match pattern you will need additional processing...

You can use:
(?<=Item)(.*?)(?=Status)|(?<=Code)(.*?)(?=Category)

Demo
If you want both in the same match you could do:
(?<=Item)(.*?)(?=Status)[\s\S]*?(?<=Code)(.*?)(?=Category)

Demo
To get 02430 , 03770 from this regex, combine group 1 and group 2 into a single string in a concatenation external to this regex.
You can come close with a regex substitution:
/[\s\S]*?(?<=Item)(.*?)(?=Status)[\s\S]*?(?<=Code)(.*?)(?=Category)|[\s\S]*/$1$2 /

Demo
